# Add a string before the last slash in other string

Tags: php, string

I've pulled the current URL into a variable. So my url is in variable $url.

Example of the `$url = 'http://domain.test/en/offers/guided-tours/neighbourhoods/academy-traces-of-the-academy-in-antwerp/'`

Now I want to add a new variable (`$venueSlug`) before the last slash. Example of value from that variable `$venueSlug = 'antwerp-city-guided'`;

The wanted result would be

```
$newUrl = 'http://domain.test/en/offers/guided-tours/neighbourhoods/antwerp-city-guides/academy-traces-of-the-academy-in-antwerp/'
```

My code looks like this:

```
function custom_post_type_link_venue ($urlsub, $post) {
 
        //get venue slug
        $venueSlug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $venueId );
        
        if (!empty($venueSlug)) {
            if (substr_count($urlsub, $replace) == 0) {
                $urlsub = str_replace($s=strrchr($urlsub, '/'), "'/'$venueSlug.$s", $urlsub);
                
            }

        }

    return $urlsub;
}
```

But it adds the new variable before every slash:

```
http://'/'.antwerp-city-guides./'/'.antwerp-city-guides./antwerp.test'/'.antwerp-city-guides./en'/'.antwerp-city-guides./offers'/'.antwerp-city-guides./guided-tours'/'.antwerp-city-guides./neighbourhoods'/'.antwerp-city-guides./academy-traces-o…ademy-in-antwerp'/'.antwerp-city-guides./ ‎
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$url       = 'http://domain.test/en/offers/guided-tours/neighbourhoods/academy-traces-of-the-academy-in-antwerp/';
$venueSlug = 'antwerp-city-guided';

$explode = explode("/",$url);
$new_url = $venueSlug."/".$explode[count($explode)-2];
print_r(str_replace( $explode[count($explode)-2],$new_url,$url));

/*
Output
http://domain.test/en/offers/guided-tours/neighbourhoods/antwerp-city-guided/academy-traces-of-the-academy-in-antwerp/
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code works in my cases, but what if there isn't a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that because there is a trailing `/` on the url, `strrchr` will find this as the last occurrence and therefore replace every `/` with the substitution.

This code uses `trim()` to remove any trailing `/`'s before calling `strrchr()` and so finds the last segment.

```
    if (substr_count($urlsub, $replace) == 0) {
        $point = strrchr(rtrim($urlsub, "/"), '/');
        $urlsub = str_replace($point, "/$venueSlug$point", $urlsub);

    }
```

Comment: Aha didn't notice that issue. Thank you very much. You code works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

One function call, one line, easy.

Match the zero-width position before the last slash which is followed by one or more non-slash character, then optionally followed by a slash, then the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9CM8C))

```
$url = 'http://domain.test/en/offers/guided-tours/neighbourhoods/academy-traces-of-the-academy-in-antwerp/';
$venueSlug = 'antwerp-city-guided';

echo preg_replace('~(?=/[^/]+/?$)~',"/$venueSlug", $url);
```